# How to loop through each file in a folder, do some action to the file and save output to a file in another folder Python

Tags: python, file, nltk, file-handling, n-gram

I have a folder with multiple files like so:

> 1980
>
> 1981
>
> 1982

In each of these files is some text. I want to loop through each of these files and do some operation to each file then save the edited file to another folder and move onto the next file and so on. The result would be that I have the original folder and then another folder with the edited version of each file in it like so:

> 1980_filtered
>
> 1981_filtered
>
> 1982_filtered

Is it possible to do this?

Currently I have some code that loops through the files in a folder, does some filtering to each file and then saves all the edits of each file into one massive file. Here is my code:

```
import os
input_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/mini_mouse'
output_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/filter_mini_mouse/mouse'
for root, dir, files in os.walk(input_location):
    for file in files:
        os.chdir(input_location)
        with open(file, 'r') as f, open('NLTK-stop-word-list', 'r') as f2:
            mouse_file = f.read().split()  # reads file and splits it into a list
            stopwords = f2.read().split()
            x = (' '.join(i for i in mouse_file if i.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in stopwords)))
            with open(output_location, 'a') as output_file:
                output_file.write(x)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `new_file = "{}_filtered".format(file)"` before `os.chdir(input_location)`. then change your second `with` statement to `with open(output_location+'/'+new_file, 'w') as output_file`

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying the file doesnt exit: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/filter_mini_mouse/mouse/1980_filtered'

Comment: Whoops, forgot to specify what kind of file. If they're text files try `new_file = "{}_filtered.txt".format(file)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what each new file is called. To do so, Python has some good string formatting methods. Fortunately, your new desired file names are easy to do in a loop

```
import os
input_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/mini_mouse'
output_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/filter_mini_mouse/mouse'
for root, dir, files in os.walk(input_location):
    for file in files:
        new_file = "{}_filtered.txt".format(file)
        os.chdir(input_location)
        with open(file, 'r') as f, open('NLTK-stop-word-list', 'r') as f2:
            mouse_file = f.read().split()  
            stopwords = f2.read().split()
            x = (' '.join(i for i in mouse_file if i.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in stopwords)))
            with open(output_location+'/'+new_file, 'w') as output_file: # Changed 'append' to 'write'
                output_file.write(x)
```

If you're in Python 3.7, you can do

```
new_file = f"{file}_filtered.txt"
```

and

```
with open(f"{output_location}/{new_file}", 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(x)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you for this! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should start by opening the `NLTK-stop-word-list` only once, so I moved it outside of your loops. Second, `os.chdir()` is redundant, you can use `os.path.join()` to get your current file path (and to construct your new file path):

```
import os
input_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/mini_mouse'
output_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/filter_mini_mouse/'
stop_words_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/NLTK-stop-word-list.txt'
with open(stop_words_path, 'r') as stop_words:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_location):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                mouse_file = f.read().split()  # reads file and splits it into a list
                stopwords = stop_words.read().split()
                x = (' '.join(i for i in mouse_file if i.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in stopwords)))
                new_file_path = os.path.join(output_location, name) + '_filtered'
                with open(new_file_path, 'a') as output_file:
                    output_file.write(x)
```

P.S: I took the liberty to change some of your variable names as they were part of python's built in words ('file' and 'dir'). If you'll run `__builtins__.__dict__.keys()` you'll see them there.